# Rounding DateTime Value to Nearest Hour with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

So, I'm trying to count the number of hours between a DateTime value and the current date with PHP. I don't want to do it by seconds and then divide it into minutes and then hours, because I'd like for it to count each hour individually. For example, 4PM-5PM would be 1, 5PM-6PM would be 2, and so on.

So if the DateTime was 2012-09-24 7:49:23 and the current DateTime was 2012-09-24 8:00:19 it would output the number 1. And if the DateTime was 2012-09-24 7:49:23 and the current DateTime was 2012-09-24 8:59:45 it would still output 1. (It wouldn't change to 2 until 9:00:00)

The DateTime I'm using for comparison is coming out a database, and if I can figure out how I will make it so that it cuts off the minutes/seconds portion of the DateTime (so that they're 0). If I could do the same with the current DateTime it would be easy. The thing is, I don't know how to do that. So how can I turn 2012-09-24 7:49:23 into 2012-09-24 7:00:00 (It still needs to be in a DateTime format so I can put it back into the MySQL database in a DateTime field)

Thanks!

EDIT: I appreciate both answers I received, but I tried tinkering with them and couldn't get exactly what I wanted. Instead, I was able to come up with on my own (through some more trial and error) what I needed to make this work. I've included it below in case anyone else has a similar issue.

```
$timea = date_format(date_create(date("c")), 'Y-m-d H:00:00');
$timeb = date_format(date_create($databasedate), 'Y-m-d H:00:00');

//hours
$diff = abs(strtotime($timeb) - strtotime($timea));
$hours = round(($diff/60/60));
```

That code should all be pretty straightforward and easy to understand. Thanks again everyone :)

Comment: Function for arbitrarily rounding PHP DateTimes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399274/339440

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of clearing individual portions of dates and times in PHP, but if you want to stick with the `DateTime` class (which I highly recommend), and you'll be using this in more than one spot, I would suggest extending `DateTime` with your own child class that wraps that functionality:

```
namespace my\name\space;

class MyWeirdMinuteAndSecondlessDateTime extends \DateTime {
    public function __construct($date, \DateTimeZone $tz = NULL) {
        parent::__construct($date, $tz);

        // Set the time to just the hour.  This is sort of
        // equivalent to the floor() function for floats.
        $this->setTime($this->format('G'), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you should give the new class a more specific name, like HourTime.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time1->setTime($time1->format('G'), 0, 0);
$time2->setTime($time2->format('G'), 0, 0);
$hourdiff = $time2->diff($time1)->format('G');
```